# SPARQL-DL (derivo API) : Retrieving instances with a specific dataproperty string value

Tags: sparql, owl-api

I'm trying to query an ontology in order to get all the instances of Person having the name "Andrea" with SPARQL-DL via owlapi:

SELECT ?i 
WHERE { Type(?i, ns:Person), PropertyValue(?i, ns:name, "Andrea") }

I'm getting this:
[http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.logException uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataFactoryImpl.getInstance()Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataFactory;
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataFactoryImpl.getInstance()Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataFactory;
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.impl.QueryParserImpl.appendLiteral(QueryParserImpl.java:514)
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.impl.QueryParserImpl.parseVariableBlankURILiteral(QueryParserImpl.java:450)
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.impl.QueryParserImpl.parseAtom(QueryParserImpl.java:314)
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.impl.QueryParserImpl.parseAtoms(QueryParserImpl.java:267)
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.impl.QueryParserImpl.parseWhere(QueryParserImpl.java:192)
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.impl.QueryParserImpl.parseSelect(QueryParserImpl.java:139)
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.impl.QueryParserImpl.parseQueryHead(QueryParserImpl.java:111)
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.impl.QueryParserImpl.parse(QueryParserImpl.java:67)
    at de.derivo.sparqldlapi.Query.create(Query.java:106)

Thanks to all,
Andrea

Comment: Have you searched for `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`? This should be quite obvious that a) you're mixing up different versions of the OWL API or b) the OWL API libs are missing.

Comment: A) the compile time and runtime libraries are different. OWLDataFactoryImpl does not have a getInstance() method any more.

Comment: By using owlapi 4 and sparql-dl 2, the error disappears. But another related problem is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40870730/2276012

Comment: @Ignazio 
I opened the related issue at https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-dl-api/issues/3