# SPARQL-DL: query for literals

Tags: sparql, owl-api

I'm using SPARQL-DL  with OWL-API in a Java application.
The Maven dependency is the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
    <artifactId>de-derivo-sparqldlapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I assume it downloads the right (compatible) version of OWL-API.
I have a class Person with some individuals. Each individual has a data property called name which ranges over a string.

By running this query:

```
SELECT ?x WHERE { PropertyValue(?y, my:name, ?x) }
```

I get this:

```
?de.derivo.sparqldlapi.Var@78 = ?"Andrea"^^xsd:string
?de.derivo.sparqldlapi.Var@78 = ?"Pippo"^^xsd:string
?de.derivo.sparqldlapi.Var@78 = ?"Pluto"^^xsd:string
```

I'm not able to get all the individuals having name equal to Pluto.

```
SELECT ?p WHERE { PropertyValue(?p, my:name, "Pluto") }
```

returns an empty set and

```
SELECT ?p WHERE { PropertyValue(?p, my:name, "Pluto^^xsd:string") }
```

returns an empty set

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype has to be put outside of the quotes, i.e. `"Pluto"^^xsd:string`

Unfortunately, from the source code I can see that the SPARQL-DL API doesn't support datatypes, see [here](https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-dl-api/blob/master/src/main/java/de/derivo/sparqldlapi/impl/QueryParserImpl.java#L514-L518) . All literals are handled as plain literals. I think you should open a feature request or implement it by yourself and then make a pull request.

Comment: I tried 
`SELECT ?y WHERE { PropertyValue(?y, my:name, "Pluto"^^string) }`
but I get the following error:

Character ")" awaited in SPARQL-DL query. (near "^^string", pos: 140, col: 52, row: 2)

Comment: For further information I paste a fragment of my toy ontology:

`......
    <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#Person"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <DataProperty IRI="#name"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#q"/>
    </Declaration>
      <DataPropertyAssertion>
        <DataProperty IRI="#name"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#q"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="&xsd;string">Pluto</Literal>
    </DataPropertyAssertion>`

Comment: Now, you forgot the prefix `xsd`. You have `"Pluto"^^string`, but it should be `"Pluto"^^xsd:string`.  Please try `SELECT ?y WHERE { PropertyValue(?y, my:name, "Pluto"^^xsd:string) }`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. 
In the following, my query variables in java code:
`private static final String PREFIXES
            = "PREFIX my: <http://www.semanticweb.org/andrea/ontologies/2016/10/untitled-ontology-83#>\n"
            + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>\n";
    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT ?y WHERE { PropertyValue(?y, my:name, \"Pluto\"xsd:^^string) }";`
I get the same error:
Character ")" awaited in SPARQL-DL query. (near "xsd:^^string", pos: 344, col: 52, row: 6)

Comment: Again, you mixed up things. Now you have the colon `:` before `^^` which is totally wrong. Why can't you copy the part I posted here? Syntax is `"Pluto"^^xsd:string` . Maybe this doesn't help with the exception you've shown but at least this should be fixed first and might already break the parser.

Comment: I'm very sorry, there was an error in my "copy and paste". I tried with this:
`private static final String QUERY = "SELECT ?y WHERE { PropertyValue(?y, my:name, \"Pluto\"^^xsd:string) }";`
and I get this:
Character ")" awaited in SPARQL-DL query. (near "^^xsd:string", pos: 344, col: 52, row: 6)

Comment: Ok, from the source code I can see that this API doesn't support datatypes, see https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-dl-api/blob/master/src/main/java/de/derivo/sparqldlapi/impl/QueryParserImpl.java#L514-L518 . All literals are handled as plain literals. I think you should open a feature request or implement it by yourself. I also added my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I opened the related issue at https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-dl-api/issues/3